Command' object has no attribute 'Context' in discord.py
I am creating a bot in discord.py, following a tutorial (here)
My code is working fine until here with commands description that look like this :
`
@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx : commands.Context) -> discord.Message:

but this time with this part :
bot.command(name="avatar")
async def send_avatar(ctx : commands.Context, user : discord.User = None) -> discord.Message:
    print("avatar command")
    if user is None :
        user = ctx.author

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"{user.name}'s profile picture",
        description=f"[Lien]({user.display_avatar.url})",
        color = discord.Color.red()
    )
    embed.set_image(url =user.display_avatar.url)
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

I raise this error : AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'Context', but on this line excactly and no other one (i have 6 other commands that work fine with the same definition)
And this is the point of commands to have a Context attribute ? Either i'm completely blind on an obvious error, or i'm completely lost.

Got an answer from the discord.py discord server ^^
the error was because of my  commands command before that had a name already used in discord.py
my bad then, problem solved
